# iOS how to schedule task & execute randomly even when the app is closed

Tags: ios, xcode, swift4

I have created an app in android where I have used FCM Job Dispatcher. Now I am working on the iOS app and did not find anything like that From the FCM.

Then I tried to look into something like that called "Services in android" to perform the background task even when the app is close. But sadly I did not find anything similar to it in iOS.

So all I am left with the is Local notifications in iOS. but I do not know if it will help me if my use case is as follow:

- App must run service only and only if the Internet is connected (wifi not mobile data), device is idle
- The service must run if the upper given conditions are fulfilled regardless of either app is running or not.

So I am very  much confused what should I select to perform such type of task. I am really confused that apps like WhatsApp and others How they actually getting calls and messages if they are not running even in background.

Please share your views that what should I use in these cases?

Comment: Look into Background Modes under the Capabilities tab of the Target's settings

Comment: @Malik I did not get what are you saying?

Comment: You can use the background refresh capability to periodically send data from your app to a server.  Voip apps like WhatsApp use PushKit to receive notifications of incoming messages and calls

Comment: @Paulw11 what is background refresh? please be specific I am new to android

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/core_app/managing_your_app_s_life_cycle/preparing_your_app_to_run_in_the_background/updating_your_app_with_background_app_refresh

Answer (score 4):

In context of performing tasks when your app is not in foreground:

1) App is in background - Simple background fetch will work

2) App has been terminated -

> **Note - If user forcefully quit the application nothing will work other than VOIP services but again VOIP services only available for the apps having audio/video calling feature**

**Case: 1 - User quit app forcefully**

You can not do anything.

**Case: 2 - System terminated the app for some reasons**

Background fetch will work for the below conditions:

- Location related services
- Audio related services
- Bluetooth/Peripheral devices data sync
- Background downloads by silent-notifications (push message having key `content-available` key in the payload )

For more reference. [read here](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH4-SW7)

Comment: background fetch is for short term task with specific time to perform. I many places I read this time is between 15 sec to 10 minutes. let suppose I have too much data to send backup to server, will it still work for me?

Comment: Background fetch gives you the 30 seconds window. App will perform tasks only for 30 sec.

Comment: let suppose. i use background fetch in iOS app, and user uses my app and create some data, now I want to send backup to server, but user kills the app instead of putting my app in background, and then after a day come back in and uses the app, and again he kills app directly. In this way the data backup will not be sent to server ever? what would you say?

Comment: You can keep a flag in your database/ user-defaults/ keychain regarding the `lastBackUpTime`. Whenever user comes in app say `appDidBecomeActive` check if difference between `lastBackUpTime` and `currentTime` is greater than 24 hours. Call data backup API silently in the background.

Answer (score 1):

In iOS, app can only waken up in a few specific conditions, like: Push Notification, background fetch, location update... So depend on your needs, you should check the Background Modes and activate the one you need in project settings:
Project Editor -> Capabilities -> Background Modes

[image: Background Modes Options]

Hope this helps.

Comment: no my simple question is like , let suppose I want to send backup to my server, and my app is closed( not running even in background) now at anytime i want to send backup to server, now How I am supposed to do that

Comment: @SharartiKAKI: I don't think you can do that on iOS. The only way to send data to your server is wake up app by one of the method in my answer, then you have very limite time (typically 30s) to send it to your server.